# I want to save range address in cell

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

[image]
I am trying to save the dynamic range address into a cell.
in my below code, range address is getting displayed in Msgbox but not able to find a way to copy & paste the address into another cell.

below is some part of my code.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Dim r2s As String
r2s = (Selection.Address)
MsgBox r2s
```

Request your help.

Comment: `Range("D1").Value = r2s`

Comment: Or alternatively, if you do not need to keep the range address as a variable string you could just remove the rest of the code and have one line of code: `Range("D1").Value = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Address`

Comment: I removed the tag `ip-address`. Please don't just use ANY tag. Try to understand what the tag is about.

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+xy+problem&rlz=1C1GCEB_enNZ953NZ953&oq=stackoverflow+xy&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i64.3905j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). What are you really trying to achieve? What will you do with  the range address once it's in the cell? You probably don't need the range in the cell at all for whatever you want to do next.